# Confusion about goAsync - BroadcastReceiver process is not killed anywhere near 10 seconds

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

According to the documentation, even after calling `goAsync` a `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method is expected to finish after 10 seconds, otherwise, the system might kill the process.

I've tested it on an emulator for an app running in the background, and neither with nor without `goAsync` the background thread is killed anywhere near 10 seconds. It's actually up to several minutes for both.
The only case when it's actually killed after 10 seconds is when I add the `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flag to the intent that triggers the broadcast.

Is this because my device is not under memory constraints?

Comment: do you mind marking the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood how [BR works](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html). Especially this part is crucial

> For this reason, you should not start long running background threads from a broadcast receiver. After onReceive(), the system can kill the process at any time to reclaim memory, and in doing so, it terminates the spawned thread running in the process. To avoid this, you should either call goAsync() (if you want a little more time to process the broadcast in a background thread) or schedule a JobService from the receiver using the JobScheduler, so the system knows that the process continues to perform active work. For more information, see Processes and Application Life Cycle.

So `goAsync` of `BroadcastReceiver` is meant to extend life of BR in general, not the `onReceive` itself - `onReceive` still runs on main thread and the ANR limit applies. But with

"Normal BR" is considered useless after returning from `onReceive`, as per reference documentation:

> goAsync()
>   This can be called by an application in onReceive(Context, Intent) to allow it to keep the broadcast active after returning from that function.

With `goAsync` you can start some background job/thread for "some time" because it's not "normal BR" - it's "BR with goAsync" now.

> Is this because my device is not under memory constraints?

And yes, I wouldn't trust in emulator in that matter.